# How to clone a kubernetes deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I need to clone my deployment including the volume. I couldn't find any resources on this question except about cloning volume using CSI driver as explained in this https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/volume-cloning.html#overview

Is there a way to clone a deployment other than renaming the deployment and deploying it again through the kubectl?

Comment: Would a replica work in this case? If not, why not?

Comment: @Felipe replica is used to scale up a deployment, i wont be able to use a replica as a separate instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to clone a deployment other than renaming the
> deployment and deploying it again through the kubectl?

Unfortunately no. At the time of this writing there is no such a tool that will allow to clone your deployment. So you will have to use the option already mentioned in the question or deploy that using helm chart.

With helm your can pass custom parameters such as `--generate-name` or  edit `values.yaml` content to quickly deploy similar deployment.

Worth mentioning here is also [Velero](https://velero.io/). A tool for backing up kubernetes resources and persistent volumes.